# How to get the content of a tkinter Text object

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to use `tkinter.Text` to create a text area in *Python*. With that, I want to get all the input they put into that text area and display it in the Entry field above it. It gives an error saying it needs two arguments.

```
from Tkinter import *

def create_index():
        var = body.get(0)
        link.insert(10,var)
        file.close()

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Link:").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Body:").grid(row=1)

link = Entry(master)
body = Text(master)

link.grid(row=0, column=1)
body.grid(row=1, column=1)
Button(master, text='Show', command=create_index).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Comment: That it **"needs to arguments"**? Please edit your question with the error it gives, that will be of great help.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the text widget? The argument requirements are well documented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get all the input from a `tkinter.Text`, you should use the method `get` from the `tkinter.Text` object you are using to represent the text area. In your case, `body` should be the variable of type `tkinter.Text`, so here's an example:

```
text = body.get("1.0", "end-1c")
```

`tkinter.Text` objects count their content as rows and columns. The `"1.0"` indicates exactly that: you want to get the content starting from line 1 and character 0 (this is the default starting point of a `tkinter.Text` object).

Here's a complete working example, where basically on the click of a button, the method `get_text` is called and adds the content of `body` to an `tkinter.Entry` object that I called `entry` (through the use of a variable of type `tkinter.StringVar`. See documentation for more information):

```
import tkinter

def get_text():
    content = body.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    entry_content.set(content)

master = tkinter.Tk()

body = tkinter.Text(master)
body.pack()

entry_content = tkinter.StringVar()
entry = tkinter.Entry(master, textvariable=entry_content)
entry.pack()

button = tkinter.Button(master, text="Get tkinter.Text content", command=get_text)
button.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

For another good example, see this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560828/how-to-read-text-from-a-tkinter-text-widget) and the first comment below.

Comment: Note that by using `END` you're getting one more character than what the user entered -- you're getting the trailing newline that tkinter automatically adds. You might want to use `"end-1c"` to get all but the last newline, or trim the last newline. It's also worth noting that in your example the use of `StringVar` is completely unnecessary. You can directly set the contents of an entry widget without using an instance of `StringVar`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ok, thanks for the critics, I will edit at least the part of `END` ;)

Comment: @BryanOakley Since you are an expert in `tkinter` and `ttk` (from what I know), could you please also have a look to this answer I tried to give yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912250/how-to-set-the-background-color-of-a-ttk-combobox/27914316#27914316. I tried to solve the problem, but there are still some problems I describe in the answer. If you could try to improve it, it could also be useful for future visitors as a good reference (who knows?). Thanks :)